# How can I prevent duplication of a common loop in my solution?

Tags: c#, .net, code-duplication, jagged-arrays

I have this loop based on a jagged array below which I will need to use more than once at different places.

How can I prevent myself to rewrite this loop again and again so that I will duplicate it?

```
      foreach (int[] columns in rowsAndColumns)
      {
          foreach (int element in columns)
          {

          }
      }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can write

```
foreach (int element in rowsAndColumns.SelectMany(col => col))
{
    // ...
}
```

instead. If you don’t like to have to type that all the time, you can abstract it into a helper method:

```
foreach (int element in rowsAndColumns.Flatten())
{
    // ...
}

// [...]

public IEnumerable<T> Flatten(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    return source.SelectMany(e => e);
}
```

Comment: Once again I remember, that I have to make myself more familiar with SelectMany ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do, but if you want to perform an action on each int, you could go for something like the extension below. Some null checking might be advisible.

```
static class RowColExtension
{
    public static void Each(this int[][] rowCols, Action<int> a)
    {
        foreach (var r in rowCols)
        {
            foreach (var c in r)
            {
                a(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do in the loop. I would approach it like this (untested code out of my head!):

```
public static class MyHelper {
    public static void ForEach(this IEnumerable<int[]> rowsAndColumns, Action<int> action) {
        foreach (int[] columns in rowsAndColumns) {
             foreach (int element in columns) {
                 action(element);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
rowsAndColumns.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension method:

```
// It's late and I'm tired, the array declaration might be off.
public static void Visit(this int[][] array, Action<int> visitor)
{
      foreach (int[] columns in array)
      {
          foreach (int element in columns)
          {
              visitor(element);
          }
      }
}

myArray.Visit(elem => Console.WriteLine(elem));
```

You can use `Action<int,int>` to get the row too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating over all elements without regard to the row or column you should turn your jagged array into a first class data structure and implement `IEnumerable` to iterate over the collection using `foreach`.  The same first-class data structure can support one-argument and two-argument indexers, range checking, etc.

**Edit:**

Here is one approach to use abstraction instead of manipulating low-level data structures.  This assumes the jagged array was allocated elsewhere.  Either way, the point is we can now use `foreach` directly on the data structure:

```
public class JaggedArray : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int[][] array;

    public JaggedArray(int[][] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int this[int row, int column]
    {
        get { return array[row][column]; }
        set { array[row][column] = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int[]> Rows
    {
        get { return array; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var row in array)
            foreach (var item in row)
                yield return item;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```